# Cypress JavaScript only able to push the last item even I use the BeforeEach() and AfterEach()

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am currently learning the Cypress and I would like to sort the array data that get from different website but I failed to push the array to my array list when I try with any cy. function, the before and after each function are working fine.

```
describe('Compare iPhone 15 Pro between eBay and Apple Store', () => {
    let productDetails = [];

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Load the existing productDetails array from localStorage if it exists
        const storedProductDetails = localStorage.getItem('productDetails');
        if (storedProductDetails) {
            productDetails = JSON.parse(storedProductDetails);
        }
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Store the productDetails array back into localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('productDetails', JSON.stringify(productDetails));
    });

    it('Visit eBay and gets the product details', () => {
        // Visit eBay and get product details
        // ...
        productDetails.push({ website: 'eBay', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: itemPrice, link: linkValue });
    });

    it('Visit Apple store and gets the product details', () => {
        // Visit Apple store and get product details
        // ...
        productDetails.push({ website: 'Apple Store', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: itemPrice, link: linkValue });
    });

    it('Print the product details array', () => {
        // Log the product details array
        for (let i = 0; i < productDetails.length; i++) {
            cy.log('Product Details: ' + JSON.stringify(productDetails[i]));
        }
    });
});
```

when I add my cy. function inside then I am not able to push the data into the array, I only able to push the last item to the array. Below is my code:

```
describe('Compare iPhone 15 Pro between eBay and Apple Store', () => {
    let productDetails = [];

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Load the existing productDetails array from localStorage if it exists
        const storedProductDetails = localStorage.getItem('productDetails');
        if (storedProductDetails) {
            productDetails = JSON.parse(storedProductDetails);
        }
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Store the productDetails array back into localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('productDetails', JSON.stringify(productDetails));
    });

    it('Visit eBay and gets the product details', () => {
        // Visit eBay and get product details
        // ...
        cy.visit('https://www.ebay.com.my/');
    
        // Search for iPhone 15 Pro 256GB
        cy.get('input.gh-tb[name="_nkw"]').type('iphone 15 pro 256gb new'); // class & attribute
        cy.get('input#gh-btn').click();
    
        cy.get('.srp-results.srp-list.clearfix').within(() => {
            cy.get('li').first().should('be.visible');
        });
    
        cy.get('li#item405343ae00 span.s-item__price span.ITALIC').invoke('text').then((price) => {
            const itemPrice = price;
            cy.log('Price: ', itemPrice);

            cy.url().then(url => {
                cy.log('Current URL:', url);
                const linkValue = url;
                productDetails.push({ website: 'eBay', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: itemPrice, link: linkValue });
                localStorage.setItem('productDetails', JSON.stringify(productDetails));
                cy.log('Product Details eBay: ', productDetails);
            });
        });
        //productDetails.push({ website: 'eBay', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: 'itemPrice', link: 'linkValue' });
    });

    it('Visit Apple store and gets the product details', () => {
        // Visit Apple store and get product details
        // ...
        cy.visit('https://www.apple.com/my/');
        cy.get('#globalnav-menubutton-link-search').click();

        cy.get('.globalnav-searchfield-input').type('iphone 15 pro 256gb new').type('{enter}');
        cy.get('[data-analytics-title="iPhone 15 Pro and iPhone 15 Pro Max - Apple (MY)"]').click();

        cy.title().should('eq','iPhone 15 Pro and iPhone 15 Pro Max - Apple (MY)');

        cy.contains(/Buy/i);
        cy.get('.welcome__lockup-cta.show').click();

        cy.contains(/Buy iPhone 15 Pro/i);

        cy.get('.rc-dimension-selector-group.form-selector-group .rc-dimension-selector-row.form-selector').first().click();

        cy.get('.colornav-items').within(() => {
            cy.get('li').first().click();
        });

        cy.get('.form-selector-title:contains("256")').click();

        cy.contains(/iPhone 15 Pro/i);
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('.rc-prices-fullprice[data-autom="full-price"]').first().invoke('text').then((price) => {
            const itemPrice = price;
            cy.log('Price: ', itemPrice);

            cy.url().then(url => {
                cy.log('Current URL:', url);
                const linkValue = url;
                productDetails.push({website: 'Apple Store', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: itemPrice, link: linkValue});
                localStorage.setItem('productDetails', JSON.stringify(productDetails));
                cy.log('Product Details: ', productDetails);
            });
        });
        //productDetails.push({ website: 'Apple Store', product: 'iPhone 15 Pro 256GB', price: 'itemPrice', link: 'linkValue' });
    });

    it('Print the product details array', () => {
        // Log the product details array
        for (let i = 0; i < productDetails.length; i++) {
            cy.log('Product Details: ' + JSON.stringify(productDetails[i]));
        }
    });
});
```

[Log from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp0sa.png)

I am expecting the result as above.

Answer (score 3):

When you visit different sites (ebay, apple) the test origin changes.

This makes Cypress reset the test window, and you will loose all the variables you have previously assigned.

It's not really a valid test, just some screen scraping attempt. Cypress tells you that the framework is not for screen scraping.

I suggest you try out some of the [Cypress examples](https://learn.cypress.io/real-world-examples) instead.